# How to find how grass's r.viewshed works programmatically?

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-2.7, viewshed

I want the Python source code of Grass's Viewshed analysis. In QGIS software there is only an .exe  file of that algorithm. Although I'm not sure whether it's written also in python or not.

Where can I find a Python (preferably using pyqgis) source code of that analysis to get more familiar with the coding of that operation?

Comment: Have you seen this source code (history) [grass/trunk/raster/r.viewshed](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/raster/r.viewshed)?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it but I'm looking for python source code since I don't know cpp.

Comment: Try to contact developers.IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amongst QGIS plugins there is a `Viewshed Analysis` Plugin which it contains the file `doViewshed.py`. In that file, there is a function called `Viewshed` which is the conventional algorithm to do viewshed analysis based on comparing distance and angle of surrounding points regarding the observer point.

If you want to get familiar with all the existing algorithms to do viewshed analysis please refer to [this source](https://www.witpress.com/Secure/elibrary/papers/MIS04/MIS04012FU.pdf).